# Quotients of quasi affine varieties and extension of scalars

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, schemes, geometric-invariant-theory

I have some questions about GIT quotients and extensions of scalars of categorical quotients:

1) Let $X$
  be a complex algebraic quasi-affine variety, $G$
  an algebraic reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$
  acting on $X$
 . What are the conditions for the existence of the categorical quotient $X//G$
 ?

2) Let $\mathcal{X}$
  be a separated scheme over a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$
 -algebra $R$
  such that the inclusion $\phi:R\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}$
  is a flat morphism, $\mathcal{G}$
  an algebraic reductive group over $R$
  acting on $\mathcal{X}$
 . Suppose the categorical quotient $\mathcal{X}//\mathcal{G}$
  exists. Denote by $\mathcal{X}_{\phi}$
 , $\mathcal{G}_{\phi}$
  and $\left(\mathcal{X}//\mathcal{G}\right)_{\phi}$
  the schemes obtained by extension of scalars from $\mathcal{X}$
 , $\mathcal{G}$
  and $\mathcal{X}//\mathcal{G}$
  via $\phi$
  (i.e., fiber products of schemes via $\phi$
 ). Is it true that $\left(\mathcal{X}//\mathcal{G}\right)_{\phi}=\mathcal{X}_{\phi}//\mathcal{G}_{\phi}$
 ? I know that this is true when $\mathcal{X}$
  is an affine scheme by Lemma 2 in Seshadri's “Geometric reductivity over arbitrary base”. Thanks in advance for any suggestions, answers or comments.